# Ruby on Rails - Calculate Size of Number Range

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2

Forgive my lack of code but I can't quite figure out the best way to achieve the following:

two strings (stored as strings because of the leading 0 - they are phone numbers) :

```
a = '0123456700'
b = '0123456750'
```

I am trying to find a way to write them as a range as follows

```
0123456700 - 750
```

rather than

```
0123456700 - 0123456750
```

which I currently have.

It's not as straightforward as getting the last 3 digits of `b` since the range can vary and perhaps go up to 4 digits so I'm trying to find the best way of being able to do this.

Comment: Why is it not `0123456700 - 50`? What decides how many digits to omit?

Comment: that's a good point, I was just thinking that myself whether it should be `- 750` or `- 50`.I'd be happy with any solution that worked regardless of the range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a method that returns the range:

```
def my_range(a, b)
  a = a.delete(" ") # remove all spaces from string                                                                                            
  b = b.delete(" ")
  a, b = b, a if a.to_i > b.to_i # a is always smaller than b                                                                                  
  ai, bi = a.to_i, b.to_i
  pow = 1
  while ai > 1
    pow += 1
    len = pow if ai % 10 != bi % 10
    ai /= 10
    bi /= 10
  end
  a + " - " + b[-len..-1]
end

puts my_range("0123456700", "0123456750")   # 0123456700 - 750
puts my_range("0123456669", "0123456675")   # 0123456669 - 675
puts my_range("0123400200", "0123500200")   # 0123400200 - 3500200
puts my_range("012 345 678", "01 235 0521") # 012345678 - 350521
```

Comment: This is inconsistent. For the OP's example, where the right two digits differ, it displays three digits separately, but for `a = "0123456669"`, `b = "0123456675"`, where the two digits differ, it displays two digits.

Comment: @sawa good point, I've added a new version that is consistent

Comment: thanks for the revised version, one oversight I missed is that people are formatting numbers with spaces - the first one worked regardless of any whitespace but for some reason the revised answer seems to throw an error with 'formatted' numbers. P.S. It's safe to assume `b > a` since `a` is always the start of the range and `b` the end of the range.

Comment: ah, managed to fix it by adding `.delete(' ' )` to the initialisations of `a` and `b` and at the end of the method, returning the unmodified a (the original formatted number) instead of the `a` with no whitespaces.

Comment: I was going to use `gsub` but that's a a better idea. I've edited my answer to show the final version.

Comment: thanks. Only difference between 'my' code is that I'm returning the original `a` with whitespaces rather than the `a` modified to remove whitespace but that's because I'm setting `a` and `b` separately from existing variables I have already (was just easier to ask the question with `a` and `b` without any complications). Just thought I'd add this comment incase someone comes along in the future and wonders why `a` doesn't have any spaces. To do the same here just create another variable at the top, e.g. `x = a` and return `x` instead of `a` or something similar.

Answer (score 3):

I'd look up the index of the first unequal pair of characters:

```
a = '0123456700'
b = '0123456750'

index = a.chars.zip(b.chars).index { |x, y| x != y }
#=> 8
```

And extract the suffix with:

```
"#{a} - #{b[index..-1]}" if index
#=> "0123456700 - 50"
```

Comment: Much nicer than my version!

Comment: nice answer, looks like some Rails magic to me. This would have been perfect originally but I think I now prefer returning `750` instead of just `50` like in @TomFenech's answer, however that is just my fault for not locking down my requirements but I'm sure others will find all the answers to this question very useful.

Comment: @martincarlin87 you can simply adjust the range, e.g. `"#{a} - #{b[index-1..-1]}"`

Comment: nice, thanks. I had already test out and accepted Tom Fenech's answer when you posted your answer, I would feel bad to unaccept and then accept yours - you don't need the points anyway :)

Answer (score 2):

From my personal library (simplified):

```
def common_prefix first, second
  i = 0
  loop{break unless first[i] and second[i] == first[i]; i += 1}
  first[0, i]
end

a = "0123456700"
b = "0123456750"
c = "0123457750"

common_prefix(a, b)
# => "01234567"

"#{a} - #{b.sub(common_prefix(a, b), "")}"
# => "0123456700 - 50"

"#{a} - #{c.sub(common_prefix(a, c), "")}"
# => "0123456700 - 7750"
```

Note. This will work correctly only under the assumption that all strings are right padded with `0` to be the same length.

Comment: thanks for sharing something from your personal library, I will give it a whirl just now.